# How to isolate overlapping polygons in the same layer with SQL

Tags: qgis, postgresql, sql

I have one layer with hundreds of polygons and I would like to attain a list of overlapping feature_ids. I read that I need to join the table to itself but I don't understand how that helps.

This is the query I wrote:

```
SELECT t1.feature_id, t1.territory_type, t2.feature_id, t2.territory_type
    FROM terr_25july2022.territory2_qtb t1

JOIN terr_25july2022.territory2_qtb t2
ON t1.feature_id = t2.feature_id AND  ST_Intersects(ST_SetSRID(t1.the_geom,4326),ST_SetSRID(t2.the_geom,4326))

WHERE t1.territory_type IN('MUNICIPALITY') AND t1.feature_id = t2.feature_id;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you mean "one polygon intersecting another" and not "one polygon intersecting itself" this should work:

```
select a.id as aid, a.geom, b.id as bid, row_number() over() as newid, st_intersection(a.geom, b.geom) as geometry
from public.overlapping a
join public.overlapping b
on st_intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
where   a.id<b.id
```

I usually add more where clauses to avoid adjacent polygons to be returned:

```
and st_dimension(st_intersection(a.geom, b.geom))=2 --The result of the intersection should be a polygon (not point or line)
and st_area(st_intersection(a.geom, b.geom))>123 --With an area > some value

aid bid newid geometry
0   7   1
0   31  2
0   32  3
```

So polygon with ids 0 and 7 are intersecting, 0 and 31, ...

[image]